# Is my plan for 'Blue Flowers Seed Mix' good?

Tags: design, sowing

I am an unexperienced gardener, and I have 10 little bags of seeds of blue flowers. Each bag's content looks like this:

[image]

The list of included species and their percentage in the mix is as follows:

[image]

Since I am not familiar with all those plants, I plan to sow them in 10 different places in the garden, having various conditions, in terms of sunlight, wind exposure, soil, walnut tree proximity, microclimate, etc., allowing nature to do its selection.

That way, at the end of vegetation season, I will know what works and what doesn't work. Next year, I could focus on what works.

I would like to call this 'design by experience'.

Does this plan sound right to you?

---

Some interesting common names of species in the mix:

- Cynoglossum amabile - *Chinese forget-me-not*
- Nigella hispanica - *Spanish fennel flower*
- Salvia farinacea - *Mealycup sage*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for optimum results I recommend starting the plant indoors in seed starter mix or just regular potting soil. By doing this you ensure a better chance of success. Also, try to identify the flower after it blooms so that you can take better care of it in the future. These are all great beginner flowers so feel free to experiment as well with different potting soils. For optimal results, I recommend putting your seed trays in a bag and placing on a windowsill until they are big enough to transplant.

Comment: Oh I like this comment by David.  You will get to learn what is what.  You'll see what works and what does not in potting soil and environmental conditions you control.  Do not forget to start in those tiny seed pots, upgrade to 3 and 4 inch and then acclimatize before planting out of doors in a double dug bed.  Fluffed soil, firmed, then plant these starts.  Use row cloth if in any doubt about errant frosts.  Plants starting in doors or in a green house have to been acclimated before being planted in the garden...and viseversa.

Comment: Thanks. But,  I want to learn what plants "work" in various areas of my garden, not what potting soil is the best.

Comment: When saying you want your plants to work in various areas you need to first have a plant, by getting the plant started you can place them in different locations to see how they do. Not all yards are built the same and there are different nutrient levels in different areas. The next step would be to place these flowers in the specified locations you are looking to plant in the container and see how they perform. I recommend an area with partial sun at first so the plants do not get sunburnt.